# jQuery: Next/Prev button that cycles through numbered elements and toggles element hide/show

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I am trying to make a next/prev button that cycles through data points on a timeline. All the popout boxes that correspond to the data points start hidden, but my objective is to be able to click the down arrow/up arrow, and have the page scroll to each datapoint in chronological order and open up the corresponding popout box.

Currently each popout box is labeled with a corresponding number which is how I target each datapoint on the timeline and open their corresponding popout box upon clicking the data point on the timeline. The code for that looks like this:

```
      $('.datapoint').click(function() {
      var popout = $(this).data('popout');
      $(".popout-" + popout).fadeToggle();
    });
```

So what I need is for the prev/next button to scroll through each datapoint and open their box. I started by making a counter variable that would get added or subtracted to on each click, and then use that variable to target each datapoint similar to the code above, however I'm struggling to get something working.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
var count = 0;

$('.timeline-scroller-down').click(function (e) {
    count++;
    e.preventDefault();
    scrollToElement(".popout-" + count);
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the dialog box in [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) for this purpose, create one dialog box for one data point. Also, I would like to add that as there will be many jQuery dialog boxes, assign unique IDs to each dialog box. Then you can display a dialog box using
    $("#popup1").dialog();

Also, assign a class to all such dialog boxes. Lets say that the class is "dialogBox". So before displaying a dialog, you will have to close any dialog box already visible. So the script would be:

```
$('.datapoint').click(function() {
$(".dialogBox").dialog("close");
var popout = $(this).data('popout');
$("#popup-" + popout).dialog();
});
```

And the click event on the scroll down button will be:

```
var count = 0;

$('.timeline-scroller-down').click(function (e) {
 $(".dialogBox").dialog("close");
count++;
e.preventDefault();
$("#popup-" + count).dialog();
});
```

EDIT:

Here is a simple implementation, which does not use jQuery UI. Create one popup box for each data point. Assign unique IDs to each popup box. Then you can display a popup box using

```
$("#popup-1").fadeToggle();
```

Also, assign a class to all such dialog boxes. Lets say that the class is "popupBox". So before displaying a dialog, you will have to close any dialog box already visible. So the script would be:

```
$('.datapoint').click(function() {
$(".popupBox").fadeOut();
var popout = $(this).data('popout');
$("#popup-" + popout).fadeToggle();
});
```

And the click event on the scroll down button will be:

```
var count = 0;

$('.timeline-scroller-down').click(function (e) {
 $(".popupBox").fadeOut();
count++;
e.preventDefault();
$("#popup-" + count).fadeToggle();
});
```

If you want to scoll the popup into view, that cannot be done using only jQuery. You can use [this jQuery plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) for scrolling an element into view.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, however switching over to jquery UI at this point would cause a lot of backtracking. Is there any way to accomplish this goal without using jquery ui?